# How to share/post something on Facebook using React native?

Tags: facebook, react-native, react-native-fbsdk

I am trying to post/share on Facebook in my react native app. But I am unable to do that.
This is my code using react-native-fbsdk lib to post something on my facebook feed:

```
    shareLinkWithDialog = async () => {
    const canShow = await ShareDialog.canShow(SHARE_LINK_CONTENT);
    if (canShow) {
      try {
        const {isCancelled, postId} = await ShareDialog.show(
          SHARE_LINK_CONTENT,
        );
        if (isCancelled) {
          Alert.alert('Share cancelled');
        } else {
          Alert.alert('Share success with postId: ' + postId);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        Alert.alert('Share fail with error: ' + error);
      }
    }
  };
```

Now, what do I do to share?

```
<View>
            <LoginButton
              onLoginFinished={
                (error, result) => {
                  if (error) {
                    console.log("login has error: " + result.error);
                  } else if (result.isCancelled) {
                    console.log("login is cancelled.");
                  } else {
                    setLoggedIn(true);
                    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then(
                      (data) => {
                        console.log(data.accessToken.toString());
                        this.getPublicProfile();
                      }
                    )
                  }
                }
              }
              onLogoutFinished={() => {
                console.log("logout.");
                setLoggedIn(false);
              }}/>
            { isLoggedIn && <Card
                title={profile.name}>
                <Image
                  source={{ uri: profileImage }}
                  style={{ width: 50, height: 50 }}
                />
                <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.shareLinkWithDialog}>
                  <Text style={styles.shareText}>Share link with ShareDialog</Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>
              </Card> 
            }
          </View>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use share dialogue provided by react-native. It will open the default share dialogue of the OS. It will have a various installed app like Message, Email, Facebook, Whatsapp etc...

```js
import { Share } from 'react-native';

 Share.share({
    message: message + ' ' + url,
    url: url,
    title: STRING.INVITATION_TO_FOMOYOLO
 }).then(({ action, activityType }) => {
    cb(action, activityType)
 }).catch((e) => console.warn('error', e));
```